# Can't create an anchor for a div tag using createElement?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, anchor

For the last 20 minutes I've been befuddled by such a simple problem that it's almost embarrassing to ask. Basically I want to create an anchor tag for a div which already exists but I want to use the DOM to create the anchor. For some reason I cannot get this simple problem to work. Tried single quotes and double quotes, moving the script tag from head to body, etc...

Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>  
</head>

<body>
<div id = "image_div">
        <img  src = "my_image.png" />          
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var DIV = document.getElementById("image_div");
   var anchor = document.createElement("a");                        
   anchor.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
   DIV.appendChild(anchor);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Example is Working Fine.. And also Append your `a` Child to DOM, but You have to Insert a text and some Sign for that it is Shown to click..

```
 var DIV = document.getElementById("image_div");
 var anchor = document.createElement("a");                        
 anchor.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
 anchor.innerText = "Click Me";
 DIV.appendChild(anchor);
```

[**See Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/d5Mw2/1/)

Or If you wanna Wrap,the `a` Anchor tag to `img` then use :

```
 var DIV = document.getElementById("image_div");
 var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
 var anchor = document.createElement("a");                        
 anchor.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
 anchor.appendChild(img1);
 DIV.appendChild(anchor);
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/d5Mw2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put any text in the anchor so it won't have any size and thus you won't see it even though it's there.

```
var DIV = document.getElementById("image_div");
var anchor = document.createElement("a");                        
anchor.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
anchor.innerHTML = "Click Me";        // <==== Add this line
DIV.appendChild(anchor);
```

Comment: You mean `innerHTML`?

Comment: @user2555139 - yep, as the code example I added to my answer shows.